# How to display values in Reduce function

Tags: json, hadoop, mapreduce

I am able to parse Json data using mapreduce in hadoop , and I wanted to display 2 string variables as it is in reduce function, Below is the code i tried

```
  public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        Double overall;
        String reviewtime;
        String line = value.toString();
        //line  = line.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        String[] tuple = line.split("\\n");            
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<tuple.length; i++){
               JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(tuple[i]);
               overall = obj.getDouble("overall");
               reviewtime = obj.getString("reviewTime");
               context.write(new Text(String.valueOf(overall)), new Text(reviewtime));

            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What to write in Reduce function so that i can disply above 2 string variables in reduce function...I am new to mapreduce and hadoop ,Please help me , below is the reduce function body

```
 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,Text,NullWritable,Text>{

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        try{



        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, This is the correct one,

```
 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text,Text,NullWritable,Text>{

    public void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        try{                    
            for(Text val : values){

                context.write(key, new Text(val.toString()));
            }
        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```